# Missing all arguments except first one in variable length arguments

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have function Log that logs variable length arguments. Unfortunately this function logs just first element. What is wrong?

```
Log(INFO,"aaa","bbb","ccc");
```

---

```
void Log(int level, char const * fmt, ...)
{

    int len = 4096;
    char buffer[len];
    int ret;
    va_list args;

        va_start(args, fmt);
        ret = vsnprintf(buffer, len, fmt, args);
        va_end(args);



    FILE *fOut;
    fOut = fopen(nvLog_File, "at");
    if(fOut)
        {
        fprintf(fOut,  "%s\n",buffer);//,
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        fclose(fOut);
        } else fprintf(stderr, "can't open file %s", nvLog_File);

}
```

Comment: What is the putput? You pass in one format string `aaaa`and two variable arguments `bbb`and `cccc`. You get what, only two strings, like it is to be expected?

Answer (score 3):

Your logging function works in a similar way to `printf()`. The first argument after log level should be formatting string, according to which the rest of arguments is interpreted. In order to print three strings, you should use `log(INFO, "%s%s%s", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc");`

Answer (score 0):

The first string argument is the format. You need to specify where/how to format the other arguments. Try something like this:

```
Log(INFO, "aaa %s %s", "bbb", "ccc");
```

You should look at a reference for printf-style functions (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/, for example).

Answer (score 0):

According to this

```
Log(INFO,"aaa","bbb","ccc");
```

You pass in `"aaa"` as the format string, so when you forward it to `printf` you should see precisley that in your log. Everything else is ignored, as you are not making use of it.